# Time derivative of the continuity equation - accelerated flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differentiation

Given a fluid with accelerated motion $\vec a= d \vec v / d t$ (in one direction). The question is to write the continuity equation using the acceleration value. The continuity equation reads

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot \rho \vec v=0 $$

Taking the derivative of both terms of the equation with respect to time yields

$$ \frac{\partial^2\rho}{\partial t^2} + \nabla \cdot \left(\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}\vec v+\rho\frac{\partial \vec v}{\partial t}\right)=0 $$

As $\vec a= d \vec v / d t= \partial \vec v / \partial t+ \vec v \nabla \cdot \vec v $ then

$$ \frac{\partial^2\rho}{\partial t^2} + \nabla \cdot \left(\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}\vec v+\rho (\vec a - \vec v \nabla \cdot \vec v)\right)=0 $$

I guess it should be the continuity equation with the use of acceleration value $\vec a$, correct?

Comment: Incompressible fluid means $\partial_t \rho+(\nabla\rho).\vec v=0$, which in addition with the continuity equation (written in terms of a partial derivatives wrt time) implies $\nabla.\vec v=0$, see wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incompressible_flow    Be careful with you derivatives: $d_t\neq \partial_t$ !

Comment: In re MathJax: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73822/what-is-the-difference-between-over-and-frac

Comment: Your original equation is incorrect.  That should be a partial derivative of density with respect to time.  And the partial derivative of velocity with respect to time at constant position is not acceleration.

Comment: The original question was written with typos, so all current replies are irrelevant. There is still no answer though..